# Getting accuracy of registration from matches

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, orb

I have a normal ORB application. Since there is no way to find out the accuracy of my homography, I am trying to get to find out the accuracy of my matches, which is the right way to do so? In my code apparently the matches after removing outliers are in raw_matches. I want after I perform the ratio test, to get the good matches and find the accuracy of them.

Code:

```
detector = cv2.ORB_create(FEATURESCOUNT)
kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

flann_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number = 6, key_size = 12, bmulti_probe_level = 1)
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})
raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, trainDescriptors = desc2, k = 2)

ratio = 0.9
mkp1, mkp2 = [], []

for m in raw_matches:
    if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
        m = m[0]
        mkp1.append( kp1[m.queryIdx] )
        mkp2.append( kp2[m.trainIdx] )

print max(distmax)
distall = sum(i for i in distmax)
print distall/len(distmax)


p1 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp1])
p2 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp2])

comps =[]
res = []

kp_pairs = zip(mkp1, mkp2)

if len(p1) >= 4:
    H, status = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    comps = getComponents(H)
    print (comps)
    print('%d / %d  inliers/matched' % (np.sum(status), len(status)))
else:
    H, status = None, None
    print('%d matches found, not enough for homography estimation' % len(p1))
```

Comment: What is `getComponents()` and where is it defined..?

Answer (score 0):

One common measure for the quality of the homography (under the assumption that errors exist in both images) is the reprojection error. When the error of each point correspondence is gaussian, then a minimal reprojection error is equivalent to the maximum likelihood estimate. It is calculated as [follows](https://picload.org/image/rcgclpoi/reprojectionerror.gif), where (x_i, x_i') are the correspondences, H is the homography and d is the geometric distance in the image, that means on the inhomogenous image points.

findHomography internally already tries to optimize the reprojection error. If a homography cannot be found (based on the passed max reprojection error), then the function should return None.

If results are plain wrong I would change ORB to AKAZE features and reduce the maximum reprojection error for inlier classification in the RANSAC scheme.
If the homography is a good coarse estimate which should be further optimized, you could use the homography to find more matches on all interest points by mapping each point with the homography and find the nearest interest point in a local neighbourhood. Afterwards you could compute findHomography again.